# Assign blender objects to every asset in another object group from BlenderGIS

Tags: modeling, objects

New User to blender... Can someone point me in the correct directions

After reading about using ai to create ski maps I thought it would be fun to try to make actual resort maps in blender https://www.skimag.com/ski-resort-life/ski-resort-maps-generated-midjourney-artificial-intelligence/

Using [BlenderGIS mod](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS) https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS I Imported a tree location into blender from QGIS containing several hundred points.
[image]

I would love to turn all the dots it added from dots to tree objects.

[image]

Comment: Hello ! You should look into vertex instancing or a geometry nodes setup. A simple setup with an instance on points node should do it. You can even vary scale, rotation that way

Comment: Thank you @Gorgious I watched this video on vertex instancing https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_nSEEcEnEA&t=133s&ab_channel=JosephBurgan3D and was able to make every point a tree!!